# When sort for data, there appear errors

Tags: python, sorting

```
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load('mymodel')    
similar = model.n_similarity(input_word_after, menu_include)  # compute cosin similarity between two sets of words.
similarity.append([all_menu_withoutNum, similar])
similarity.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print("First 100 similarity menu: ")
for item in similarity[0:100]:  
   print(item)
```

Above are my code. which is trained word2vec model for testing cosin similarity. Now get follwing error:

```
D:\python2.7.9\lib\site-package\numpy\core\_methods.py:55:RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice. warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice" RuntimeWaening) D:\python2.7.9\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:67: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount) F:/testModel/keywordRetireve.py:47: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less similarity.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) Traceback (most recent call last):  File "F:/testModel/keywordRetireve.py", line 53, in <module> gettingSimi = getting_similarityS(restaurants)  File "F:/testModel/keywordRetireve.py", line 47, in getting_similarityS
similarity.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If there someone knows the reason, please help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reword it, but the answer is in the exception message:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>   Use a.any() or a.all()

So instead of this:

```
similarity.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Try this if you want to get `True` if *all* values in the array evaluate `True`:

```
similarity.sort(key=lambda x: x[1].all(), reverse=True)
```

Or this if you want `True` if *any* value in the array evaluates `True`:

```
similarity.sort(key=lambda x: x[1].any(), reverse=True)
```

Comment: @ShuiArr, see the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I am testing it now, see the result.

Comment: It seems working as you suggest, Now, the error occur again, but D:\python2.7.9\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:55: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
D:\python2.7.9\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:67: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)

Comment: Those are totally separate, and they're only Warnings, so they won't halt execution. Still worth looking at them. You can ask another question about those.